# Visual Studio Designer Reference Error

Tags: visual-studio

After I have rebuilt solution and open *Form* in Designer this kind of message appears:

http://s1.postimg.org/3vilbssdp/lic.png

Before everything works fine. Is it broken references fault? Or maybe the problem is in *licenses* file? Where I should search for solution?

What is interesting: when I run Designer at the beginning of work everything is fine but when I rebuild solution everything collapses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be referencing the library incorrectly.  If you have a reference to another project make sure that it is a `Project Reference` and not a reference to the dll in that project's bin folder.

If you try to reference something in the bin folder you can get tripped up by the order that Visual Studio decides to build your projects.  By using project references visual Studio can determine the correct build order and dependencies.

Comment: I have solved this problem using this trick:
http://errors-solutions-solved-problems.blogspot.com/2013/01/visual-studio-load-file-assembly-bug.html